# Which OOP Paradigm should I use?

Tags: java, android, oop

I have near around 25 activities, now I need to write a function which is same in around 3 to 5 activities now I can use any of these OOP paradigm?

- A static method
- A singleton class (Application class)
- A parent class (Inheritance)
- Create new instance of the class where we have created this
  function (Composition).

Currently, I am using Composition, Can anyone please tell me how do you all decide which paradigm is best for which case?

Comment: It might be easier for us to help you if you could show us some of what you have so far.

Comment: Maybe better at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @mypetlion I am currently using Composition.

Comment: Favour Composition over Inheritance - classic OOP guideline. Simply put, which suits best IS-A or HAS-A.  It would seem HAS-A otherwise all Activities would suit the IS-A, not the 3-5 instances you've got.  If neither suit then think about a static utility method possibly using generic types to offer more flexibility.

Comment: This depends. You can get a lot of generalized responses, but to get an answer that actually fits *your* situation, we'll have to see some code. If the function has no side effects, then creating a `static` utility method may be the best approach, which is *not* hard to test, as long as the function doesn't have side effects.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use `Inheritance` in this case because you don't extend just what you do, but what you represent, and this doesn't seem the case. The `Utility` and `Singleton` are similar approaches and might suite you well but make the code more difficult to test. The `Composition` seems more natural because you want to add a particular (independent) functionality to a subset of activities, and allows easy testing as well.So, I would say that the `Composition` is the best choice.

Comment: By "Utilility" do you mean having a Utility class and creating its instance ?? Because that means Composition which I was doing previously ?

Comment: In general the term utility class is used for classes with just static methods.

Comment: Static methods are not hard to test if they don't have side effects, and may actually be the proper solution (depending on his code, which we have yet to see). Problem is, static methods are not OOP, they're procedural, which conflicts with his title.